# Microsoft Bot V4 Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, botframework

I am using a login dialog with below code. How do I know if user is authenticated or not ?

```
    namespace Sample.Dialogs
    {
     public class LoginDialog : ComponentDialog
     {
        private readonly BotStateService _botStateService;
        public LoginDialog(string dialogId, BotStateService botStateService) : base(dialogId)
        {
            _botStateService = botStateService ?? throw new 
             System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(botStateService));
             InitializeWaterfallDialog();
        }

        private void InitializeWaterfallDialog()
        {
            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
               nameof(OAuthPrompt),
               new OAuthPromptSettings
               {
                   ConnectionName = "",
                   Text = "Please login",
                   Title = "Login",
                   Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
                }));
            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));
            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                PromptStepAsync,
                LoginStepAsync

            }));
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);  //InitialDialogId = $" 
           {nameof(LoginDialog)}.mainFlow";
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        { 
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;

            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return  await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null , cancellationToken);

            }
        }

        private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
            // if token exists
            if (tokenResponse != null)
            {
                // welcome user
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged 
                 in."),cancellationToken);
                // Display the name 
                await OAuthHelpers.GetUserDetail(stepContext.Context, tokenResponse);
                return await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
            }

            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful 
            please try again."), cancellationToken);
            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        }
   }
}
```

Now, even after successful login user have to type something to know if they logged in or not. However, we want once the login is (Azure AD) successful message should push to user from bot saying that your name is this and you have successfully logged in.

How do we achieve this. ?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you saying that you never hit this line or it's hit after successful log in?
```await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."),cancellationToken);```

And why are you calling ```CancelAllDialogsAsync``` in the success cenario?

Comment: Refer to this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs)